# Datagrid delete column with confirmation

Tags: datatable

This is my code

```
function GetLaminasyon() {
                    $('#tblLaminasyon').DataTable().destroy();
                    $('#tblLaminasyon').DataTable( {
                        "paging":   false,
                        "ordering": false,
                        "info":     false,
                        "searching":false,                      
                        "data": objLaminasyon,
                        "columns": [
                            { "data": "Name" },
                            { "data": "Amount" },                           
                            { "data": "Price" },
                            { 
                                "data": "Id",
                                "render": function(data,type,row) {
                                    var actionButton = "<button type='button' id='btnDeleteLaminasyon' class='btn btn-danger'>Sil</button>";
                                    return actionButton;
                                }}
                        ]
                    } );
                }
```

How can i a delete confirmation for this datatable? I tried to find the solution but i couldnt find it. thanks a lot.

Comment: do you have any ideas?